# Two different answers for same expression in C

Tags: c, linear-regression

I have an expression which does the same calculation. When I try to do the whole calculation in a single expression and store it in variable "a", the expression calculates the answer as 0. When I divide the equations in two different parts and then calculate it, it gives the answer -0.332087. Obviously, -0.332087 is the correct answer. Can anybody explain why is this program misbehaving like this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    double a, b, c;
    int n=0, sumY=0, sumX=0, sumX2=0, sumY2=0, sumXY=0;
    n = 85;
    sumX = 4276;
    sumY = 15907;
    sumX2 = 288130;
    sumY2 = 3379721;
    sumXY = 775966;
    a = ((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX));
    b = ((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY));
    c = ((n*sumX2) - (sumX*sumX));
    printf("%lf\n", a);
    printf("%lf\n", b/c);
}

Output:
0.000000
-0.332097
```

Comment: all your operands are `int`, so you're doing integer division, which throws out any decimal value, leaving 0. The only floating point division you're doing here is `b/c`, which gives you the decimal value. If you case just one of your `int` operands to `double`, it will do floating point division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program

```
a = ((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX));
```

all the variables in the right hand side are of type int, so it will produce a result of type int. The true answer -0.332097 is not a int value, so it will be converted to a valid int value, namely 0. And this 0 is assigned to variable `a`.

But when you do

```
b = ((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY));
c = ((n*sumX2) - (sumX*sumX));
printf("%lf\n", b/c);
```

The variable `b` and `c` are of type double, so the expression `b/c` produce a double typed value and the true answer -0.332097 is a valid double value. Thus this part of your code give a right result.

Answer (score 2):

In first equation i.e. `a = ((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX))` both numerator and denominator will give integer results and the value stored in a will also be integer as integer/integer is integer. In second and third expression as you are solving them individually both b and c will be stored in double and double/double will result in a double i.e. a decimal value.

This problem can be solved by using type casting - or better still using `float` for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add **double** before your calculation, so after you do your integer calculation in "a", it will convert it to **double**.

```
a = (double)((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX));
```

Comment: Even better, use `float` or `double` types

Answer (score 0):

First of all `(INTEGER)/(INTEGER)` is always an `INTEGER`. So, you can typecast it like `a = (double)(((n*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX)));`

#### OR

We know that any number (n ∈ ℂ), multiplied by 1.0 always gives the same number (n). So, your code shall be like:

`a = ((n*sumXY*1.0L) - (sumX*sumY)) / ((n*sumX2)-(sumX*sumX));`

Multiplying by `1.0L` or `1.0f` converts the whole arithmetic operation to `long double` data type.
Now you can print the number (-0.332097) to `stdout`.

### Non-standard Code

Your code is:

```
void main()
{
     //// YOUR CODE
}
```

Which is non-standard `C`. Instead your code should be like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     //// YOUR CODE
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change all your INTEGERS to DOUBLES. That should solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

The type of 1st expression is int whereas in 2nd expression it is double.

Comment: Factually correct, but not a helpful answer